# Import-CSV returns blank values for the variables?

Tags: powershell, csv, import-csv

I utilized some Power Shell code to read a word document table and place the certain parts of the table inside of a csv sheet. When I try to `Import-Csv` the csv sheet and use the variables that have been placed inside I am unable to. The variables themselves are output as blanks. The data within the csv exists but the script is unable to read it.
My csv reading file Code:

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#_________________________________EXCEL TIME_________________________________

  
#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\Users\username\Desktop\newusers.csv


#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below
    $fname = $User.fname
    Write-Output $fname
    $fname = $fname | Out-String
    Write-Output $fname
    $lname = $User.lname
    Write-Output $lname
    $lname = $lname | Out-String
    Write-Output $lname
    #$fn1 = $fname.Substring(0,1)
    #$username = "$fn1$lname"
    $jobtitle = $User.jobtitle
    $jobtitle = $jobtitle | Out-String 
    $department = $User.department
    $department = $department | Out-String
    $manager = $User.manager
    $manager = $manager | Out-String
    $pagernumber = $User.pagernumber
    $pagernumber = $pagernumber | Out-String
    Write-Output $fname
    Write-Output $lname

    }
    pause
```

I believe this problem stems from the fact that I placed an object into a csv file. However, I am unsure how/why it would go wrong because of that. I do not receive any error messages I only receive blank space When I `Write-output` the variables that are supposed to exist.

The CSV File that gets inputted: [My CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQKD8.png)

```
"fname","lname","jobtitle","department","manager","pagernumber"
"Test","Taco","Testing Dummy","TestingDepot","BIGboss","9999"
"Test","TJ","TestingDummy","4220","BIGboss","9990"
```

The CSV is created when the below script runs. The below script will take information from a Word document table and edit it slightly before placing it within the csv file.

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory


#Assign the document folder
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\username\Desktop\NewUserForms\"

forEach ($doc in $files) {

#Create word application object
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

#Assign document path
$doc = $doc.ToString()
$documentPath = "C:\Users\username\Desktop\NewUserForms\$doc" 

#open the document
$document = $word.Documents.Open($documentPath)

#list all tables in doc
$document.Tables | ft


    $fname = $document.Tables[1].Cell(6,2).range.text
    $lname = $document.Tables[1].Cell(8,2).range.text
    $jobtitle = $document.Tables[1].Cell(15,2).range.text
    $department = $document.Tables[1].Cell(16,2).range.text
    $manager = $document.Tables[1].Cell(17,2).range.text
    $pagernumber = $document.Tables[1].Cell(4,2).range.text.Substring(17)

#get info from a certain part of the table in the word doc
$information = [PSCustomObject]@{
    fname = $fname -replace '\W',''
    lname = $lname -replace '\W',''
    jobtitle = $jobtitle -replace '\W',''
    department = $department -replace '\W',''
    manager = $manager -replace '\W',''
    pagernumber = $pagernumber -replace '\W',''
                }


Write-Output $fname
Write-Output $lname


#Write-Output $information
$information | Export-Csv -NoTypeInfo -Append -Path C:\Users\username\Desktop\newusers.csv

#Close the document
$document.close()

#Close Word
$word.quit()
                    }
```

Comment: You may share some sample data from your CSV file as well.  (A few sanitized lines would be enough)  ;-)

Comment: `Import-csv` by default uses the _comma_ as field delimiter. Perhaps (we cannot see it..) your CSV file uses some other character like the semi-colon. If that is the case, use parameter `-Delimiter` on the Import-Csv line to tell PowerShell what to split the values on.

Comment: When opening the CSV file in notepad it is shown as being separated by commas. In addition to this there are no blank spaces or strange characters. :/

Comment: The columns in your csv are called ```fname``` and ```lname```, but you're trying to access properties called ```$User.firstname``` and ```$User.lastname```. One good practice is to enable ```$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"``` and ```Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"``` at the top of your script, then you would have seen an error like ```ParentContainsErrorRecordException: The property 'firstname' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists.```

Comment: My apologies, I was messing with it just now before I edited it and changed that all around so that it was easier to type. This is not what is currently causing it to not read the csv file. If I were to ```Write-Output $jobtitle``` it would still only show a blank space. (I have edited the question to not show this error)

Comment: Can you post the first couple of lines of the raw csv file contents *as text* (i.e. not a screenshot of the file open in excel). Without seeing the header row and the delimiters, quotes, etc of the csv format it’s more or less impossible to say what might be going wrong…

Comment: I posted the raw csv lines.